# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute ''cantidad_update"

Tags: python, django

how are you? I have this error when trying to subtract the values ​​in an IF where it is subtracted if the quantity_update is greater than 0. and if it does not subtract only the quantity.

models.py:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    especialidad = models.ForeignKey('Especialidad')
    articulo = models.ForeignKey('Articulo')
    fecha_entrega = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    fecha_pedido = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,null=True, blank=True)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    cantidad_update = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    estado_update = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

class Articulo(models.Model):
    cod_experto = models.CharField(max_length=999, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
```

Views.py Query:

```
def Entregar(request, id_especialidad):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        especialidad = Especialidad.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
        pedido = Pedido.object.filter(especialidad=especialidad).filter(estado='pendiente')
        if pedido.cantidad_update > 0:        #Here is the error!
            pedido.articulo.stock -= pedido.cantidad_update 
        else:
            pedido.articulo.stock -= pedido.cantidad

        pedido.save()
        pedido2 = Pedido.objects.filter(especialidad=especialidad).filter(estado='pendiente').update(estado='entregado').update(fecha_entrega=datetime.date.today())

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/solicitar/lista_super/%s/' % id_especialidad)
```

This would be relevant and I do not know that I'm missing, some help please!

Comment: What is the error here?

Comment: ¡I don't know! really dont know :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
pedido = Pedido.object.filter(especialidad=especialidad).filter(estado='pendiente')
```

` to

```
pedido = Pedido.object.filter(especialidad=especialidad).filter(estado='pendiente')[0]
# or use for x in y  to iterate each item`,
```

Your error occurs because `filter()` returns `Queryset`, not `Pedido Object`!

Comment: It works fine, thank you very much, but I only have one problem with this solution, since I only perform the subtraction of an order of an amount, the others with quantity_update> 0 have not been solved so it just did with one of the first in this case. How to get it done with more than one amount, thanks for your good mood!

Comment: use `for in` iteration ,for example:`for p in Pedido.object.filter(xxx):`,this is how to resolve your problem! [Django Queryset reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference)

Comment: @DemaroCreate using [0] fails when there is no data after filter, which will lead to 500 error. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

But in your case why are you using filter instead of get!

Using `pedido = Pedido.object.filter(especialidad=especialidad).filter(estado='pendiente')[0]` as long as there is data to retrieve. But **when there is no data ? the query fails and the page returns 500 error. Because `None` queryset will not have `0th` element.**

Consider using `get_object_or_404` since you want to get single object. Use something like which will be fail

```
def Entregar(request, id_especialidad):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        especialidad = get_object_or_404(Especialidad, id=id_especialidad)
        pedido = get_object_or_404(Pedido, especialidad=especialidad, estado='pendiente')
        if pedido.cantidad_update > 0:  # Here is the error!
            pedido.articulo.stock -= pedido.cantidad_update
        else:
            pedido.articulo.stock -= pedido.cantidad

        pedido.save()
        pedido2 = get_object_or_404(Pedido, especialidad=especialidad, estado='pendiente')
        pedido2.update(estado='entregado').update(fecha_entrega=datetime.date.today())
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/solicitar/lista_super/%s/' % id_especialidad)
```

Comment: Your answer is comprehensive!